# How big is the Minecraft universe compared to real life?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just learned that each block is one meter in Minecraft, and that Steve is about 2 meters tall. Normally, an adult would be about 2 meters, and a kid, less. I wonder how many meters the real world is? How big is the Minecraft universe compared to real life?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a thought experiment and has no bearing to gameplay.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. We deal with lots of questions that don't have any "bearing" on gameplay. They are common and pervasive throughout the site and have been determined to be on topic several times.

Comment: @Ktash Thought experiments have no place here at all.  They're nothing more than pie in the sky questions.

Comment: @Frank Except they do. We have this **exact question** for several different games now. And, again, have determined before that they are on topic. A few times now.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. Partly because I see no problem with the question but mostly because I disagree with @StrixVaria using his mod diamond to force-close questions that aren't obviously off-topic.

Comment: This is obviously off topic because comparing game mechanics to how the real world works is nonsense.

Comment: @Ktash I can find one, for WoW, where it actually *has* real world distance measurements.  Does Minecraft have something similar?  If not, this is nothing more than a curiosity.

Comment: @Frank There are also ones for Skyrim and KSP. And those are just the ones that were easy to find in my quick search. And of course it's curiosity, *it's a question*. But even if you take "curiosity" as a bad thing, some of our highest rated questions probably fall under that broad categorization. In fact, the Skyrim map question is on page 4 of our highest voted questions. Also, "they're curious" is **not** a valid close reason.

Comment: @Ktash Questions having no bearing on gameplay tend to be thought experiments. Yes, we can ask random unrelated questions that do nothing but assuage curiosity, but there is a limit. That limit is, "is this useful in any sense?" This one is not. It does absolutely nothing to save itself.

Comment: Usefulness is not a determiner of what makes something on or off topic. That's what votes are for.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Actually, it is. As Grace has said before, we don't allow questions about things that don't really exist. She used the example of, "Why aren't companion cubes octagons? Or circles?". It's a thought experiment. Not an actual question.

Comment: The example you give is a developer intent question. That's why it's off topic.

Comment: This is nonsense! The Elder Scrolls games has a lore tag and it mentions about its universe and life, not gameplay related. *[rant redacted --bp]*

Comment: Related meta post: [What's with the hostility about how big Minecraft is?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11345/4797)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A single solid block in Minecraft is [1m on a side](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Solid_block#Heights). In modern Minecraft, the practical boundary is the [World Border](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_border), which encompasses an area of 60 million blocks, going from -30,000,000 to + 30,000,000, and centred on 0, 0. So end to end, the Minecraft world is 60,000 km across.

To put that in perspective, the distance from the Earth to the Sun is [150 million km](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/k-4/features/F_Measuring_the_Distance_Student_Pages.html).

The area of the Minecraft world is 3600 million square kilometers. The area of the Earth's surface is [510 million square kilometers](http://www.universetoday.com/25756/surface-area-of-the-earth/). So the traversable Minecraft world surface is about 7 times the surface area of the Earth.

Answer (score -4):

The world of Minecraft is infinite. There is no way to measure the scaling to our world. Each block in Minecraft is roughly a 3'x3'x3', or 1 yard per side. This would make most things in Minecraft over-sized, or under-sized scaling to the real world. Therefore everything is "un-measurable" to us. In short: The world of Minecraft is ∞x our world. I hope this helps you :)

Comment: -1: This is not correct at all. i) The Minecraft world is not infinite. ii) Where do you get 1 yard from?

Comment: @ire_and_curses - while the official measurement used by Mohjang is in meters, there are a lot of tutorials that consider blocks as 1 yard high for those more used to working in Imperial notation. It's even mentioned on the [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Measuring_distance)

Comment: Yeah, given the other distortions involved, 10% really isn't significant.