# Is I possible to load earth in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to load 3 billion blocks in Minecraft as I was thinking of rlcraft what if they turn the Mc world into earth since from the earth surface to the outer core is >2905 to <2970 kilometre and one cubic meter is one Minecraft block and 1 kilometre is 1000 meter and since one chunk is 2.9 million metersx16x16 and Minecraft can load the minimum of 4 chunks (2 by 2) it will have to load around 2.9696 billion block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you reach the edge of the world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world)

Comment: Other possible dupe target: [How big is the Minecraft universe compared to real life?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/256002/185203)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a dupe of either to me. From what I understood, the question could be formulated as: "After calculations, it seems like Earth would be around 2.9696 billion Minecraft blocks big. With that number in mind: would it be possible to load the Earth in Minecraft?"

Comment: The second suggested dupe comes close, but that's only taking into account the surface area. Since Earth is spherical an answer to this question requires a little more calculating (mostly volume). But I'm not sure if the OP wants to know if a representation of Earth would fit a Minecraft world, or if a Minecraft world has a volume of at least 2.9696 billion blocks.

Comment: https://buildtheearth.net/

Comment: Sorry for my typos and stuff but some more knowledge one Minecraft world is 3.5 trillion chunks assuming  the world is 30mil by 30 mil I’m saying that the distance from earth surface to beginning of outer crust (liquid) is 2.9 mil meters and so I’m asking can our computers load 4 chunks which is minimum (2 chunks=2 by 2)which is 16x16x4x2.9million meters

Comment: Responding to second guy I’m saying 2.96 billion blocks in 4 Minecraft chunks not the whole earth

Comment: I'm getting confused. It's impossible to place 2.96 billion blocks in just 4 chunks. Wasn't a chunk just 384 block tall 16x16 segment? That'd be only 98,304 blocks... So 4 chunks can only place 393,216 blocks, it's not even close to just a million...

Comment: You know, your question itself sounds valid according to @LeoS. 's summary of your post. But your writing is making it confuse everyone thus leading downvote (I guess). Perhaps it would be much better understood if you wrote the questions in English from your native language using some sort of translation software. Even if there are some mistakes, it would be easier for us to correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minecraft world has a fundamentally different shape to earth.

Each minecraft block is nominally 1 meter.

The earth is a sphere, about 12700 kilometers in diameter.

The buildable minecraft world is a thin square. In vanilla minecraft it's about 60000 kiliometers in each of the horizontal dimensions (and this can trivially be increased by mods) but only 384 meters tall (increased from 256 meters in earlier versions).

So no, earth cannot be accomodated within the standard minecraft world.

It's possible to increase the height of the world through a data pack, but I cant find any sources on what if anything the hard limits are. In any case I think simply increasing the world height would result in system overload long before you reached a world tall enough to accommodate the earth.

There is however a mod called "cubic chunks" which splits up the world into chunks in three dimensions rather than minecraft's normal two. With such a mod I see no fundamental reason a model of the earth could not be accommodated.